# Copy all files recursively without replacing

Tags: file-copy

Scenario:

Source dirs:

```
/day1/hour1/instance1/files.ext
/day1/hour1/instance2/files.ext
/day1/hour1/instance3/files.ext
/day1/hour2/instance1/files.ext
/day1/hour2/instance2/files.ext
```

etc..

Target dir (already exist):

```
/day1/hour1/instance4/files.ext
/day1/hour1/instance5/files.ext
/day1/hour1/instance6/files.ext
/day1/hour2/instance6/files.ext
/day1/hour2/instance7/files.ext
```

I have to copy all files from source to target.

As you can see I have a same tree, that means same day, and same hours, but different instance from source and target.
I need to copy all dir and files from source in the same exactly tree in target but preserving all files that are already in target folder.

How could I achieve this?

`cp -R` is what I need? or do I need to add some more parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `rsync`:

```
rsync --archive --ignore-existing source_dir/ target_dir/
```

This will copy the `source_dir` hierarchy inte `target_dir`, but will not overwrite any files in the `target_dir` that already exists.

Answer (score 1):

I think I would use rsync instead. With rsync you can copy and synchronize the data. Typical parameters are:

```
rsync -avh source destination
```

v is for verbose
a for recursive and preserves file permissions, ownerships and timestamps
h is for making human-readable output numbers